# selecting element that is inside of an if statement xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-16

What is the ideal way to select an element that is inside of if-else statements? For example, if in a qweb view, there is a statement that says something like:

```
t-if="something"

    <div>INFORMATION</div>

t-else-if="somethingElse"

    <div>SOME OTHER INFROMATION</div>
```

Now, what is the ideal way to write an XPath expression that modifies both? If I do //div[1] and then //div[2], it says it can't find the second element, which is true I guess because it'll only be there if the second condition is true. However, that'll also make it //div[1], no? But if I only do //div or //div[1], it doesn't affect the second one, even when the second condition is true. What am I missing here?

Comment: The view arch is [resolved](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#view-resolution) before rendering the view, both div tags should be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a better approach available, you can use this example below

```
<xpath expr="//t[@t-if='something']" position="after">
....
</xpath>
```